# APM resource names (HTTP endpoints) grouped by pod name (instance names)

Tags: datadog

I can't seem to figure out how to query out this basic table of information from APM trace data - any help will be appreciated.

I want to COUNT all resource names (`resource_name`) grouped by pod name (`pod_name`) and write to out to a table.  And I want this represented on a dashboard.  Example:

```
Resource Name                               Pod Name                     Count
GET /api/tenants/{tenantId}/users           application-pod-1            222
GET /api/tenants/{tenantId}/users           application-pod-2            151
GET /api/tenants/{tenantId}/projects        application-pod-1            34
GET /api/tenants/{tenantId}/projects        application-pod-2            37
```

I cant seem to query APM data using dashboard tools:
[image]

And if I try create a custom metric, I don't get the option of `resource_name` in the count column (in fact, only duration is an option):

[image]

Furthermore, I cant do this in Trace Analytics either since the querying capabilities are very limited.

Comment: Is my only option to create a custom (redundant) tag on these APM spans?  That's frustrating since the data is already there in Datadog.